# Is partial Batch commit possible in Spring JDBC or JDBC?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, batch-processing, spring-jdbc

My code is going to insert 50 records as part of batch.
In case if there is an error with 25th record is there way

1. Skip that record and go ahead with rest of records
2. Insert records from 1 - 24
3. Get position of the failed record

Comment: No. Its not the one record that fails, its the transaction that fails. If you want to prevent failures you'll need to validate records before you attempt to insert them.

Comment: @Gimby the insert may fail for valid data also for example if there is no space available.

Comment: Yes, but at such a critical failure you WANT everything to stop. In the example of no space, records 26 and up are also not going to fit.

Comment: No we are going to store failed records at different places and take care of the same in a different way. So if any records fails I want to get rest of the records inserted or get at least position of the failed record So we can proceed with other records.